# openstack-dashboard installation - set up via apt returns many python errors including "insecure permissions"

Tags: software-installation, permissions, openstack

I am a new member of Openstack and of course I have some problems.

I tried to install openstack newton on my laptop using Ubuntu 16.04.

- Intel i7
- 16Gb Ram
- 1TB hard disk

I followed the steps from [this tutorial](https://docs.openstack.org/newton/ins), properly I think (all services are up and running).

When I tried to Verify operation using `http://controller/horizon` or http:// localhost/horizon or `http://my_IP/horizon`, I get the same error

```
500 Internal Server Error
```

I made some changes like `chmod` of `secret_key` to `777` (I do not know how to revert this) and finally I decided to uninstall it and install again but I have had no success because I get the error below during the installation.

```
root@Controller:~# apt install openstack-dashboard 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done 
openstack-dashboard is already the newest version (3:11.0.2-0ubuntu1~cloud0). 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 
1 not fully installed or removed. 
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used. 
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y 
Setting up openstack-dashboard (3:11.0.2-0ubuntu1~cloud0) ... Collecting and compressing static assets... 

Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "manage.py", line 25, in <module> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line utility.execute() 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 303, in execute settings.INSTALLED_APPS 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__ self._setup(name) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__ mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module __import__(name) 
File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/settings.py", line 335, in <module> from local.local_settings import * # noqa 
File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/local/local_settings.py", line 125, in <module> SECRET_KEY = secret_key.generate_or_read_from_file('/var/lib/openstack-dashboard/secret_key') 
File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/horizon/utils/secret_key.py", line 70, in generate_or_read_from_file key = read_from_file(key_file) 
File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/horizon/utils/secret_key.py", line 51, in read_from_file os.path.abspath(key_file)) horizon.utils.secret_key.FilePermissionError: Insecure permissions on key file /var/lib/openstack-dashboard/secret_key, should be 0600. 
dpkg: error processing package openstack-dashboard (--configure): subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing: openstack-dashboard 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Is there any solution or workaround to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've (almost) got your answer right there:

> Insecure permissions on key file `/var/lib/openstack-dashboard/secret_key`, should be `0600`

1. Set the given permission mask on the indicated file:

   ```
   sudo chmod 0600 /var/lib/openstack-dashboard/secret_key
   ```
2. Configure half-installed packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -f
   ```

Comment: I am a brand new user on askubuntu :)

Comment: @Costas: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You'll get the hang of it eventually! :-) You can also [take the tour](/help/tour) to get yourself started.